# Scatter Plot Matrices

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a matrix `mat[n,m]` and I'd like to use *splom* to plot the scatterplots of `mat[,"col4"]` as a function of all other column values. Also I'd like to add different colors to points of certain row numbers which are stored in `rownID[]`. I've seen examples using *splom* but they plot all variables against all variables and use group of columns to change the color of points. Is it possible to do what I want using *splom* (or other R function)?

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <-  matrix(sample(0:100, 16), ncol=4)

dimnames(mat) <- list(rownames(mat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "row"),
                          colnames(mat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))

mat
     col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   26   19   58   61
row2   37   86    5   33
row3   56   97   18   66
row4   89   62   15   42

rowID <- matrix(c(1,3), ncol=1, nrow=2)
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033003/1262767

I've been using *featurePlot* function of **caret** package but I don't know how to change color of some specific points (that's why I'm interested in *splom*):

```
featurePlot(mat, mat$col4, plot = "scatter",
            ## Add some space between the panels
            between = list(x = 1, y = 1), main = "testSet",
            ## Add a background grid ('g') and a smoother ('smooth')
            type = c("g", "p", "s"))
```

Comment: This is not R code. Please provide the code you would actually use to create `mat`.

Comment: What output do you want? Just a panel of 3 scatterplots - "R" vs. the other 3?

Comment: Yes, that's it. And then to color points of some specific rows.

Comment: Just edited my post with some R code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really seem like a good fit for `splom`. I think you're be better off reshaping your data and using a standard `xyplot`. For example

```
library(reshape2)
mm<-melt(cbind(data.frame(mat), high=1:nrow(mat) %in% rowID), c("col4","high"))
xyplot(col4~value|variable, mm, groups=high)
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: If I want to add another group to color points of `row4` how can I do it based on your code? Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by that. The general idea is that you need need to add a column to your `mat` data that indicates the color for each row. In this example, I `cbind` such a column prior to melting; but you can do that however you like.

Comment: What I meant was: what if I wanted to assign a different color to `row4`, i.e. another vector `rowID2` <- `matrix(4,ncol=1)`? I need to add another column or change the column you added already? Thanks

Comment: You would not want to add an additional column; just change what's already where. You should try to make the each question you post on this site focus on a specific problem. If you have a lot of questions about coloring, you should probably open a new question. It's not good form to bring up issues in the comments that were not properly addressed in the original question.

Comment: Ok! I'll try do change the code to suit my needs before posting a new question. As a side note you could tweak your answer to address this additional variable: three different colors specified in two different vectors (rowID (2 rows) and rowID2 (1 row)). Thanks